# How much data does RealmSwift save?

Tags: swift, realm

It's my first time working with Realm on Swift, and even though I read through the entire Realm docs, I seem to be failing to understand some simple and fundamental concepts.

When you create an Object class in Realm, and you make an instance of that class, does this automatically get saved onto the Realm database?

Say I'm trying to do is create an Object class 'foo' that contains a list of Object class 'bar'

```
dynamic var objectList: List<bar>
```

Then, I want to update the List with a new instances of the 'bar' class. 
I think that updating the List does not create a new instance that gets saved in Ream, but I'm afraid that since I am creating new 'bar' instances that go into my list, that all the instances of the 'bar' class will therefore be unnecessarily saved.

In other words, say alpha, beta, and gamma are instances of the 'bar' class.

I will create a greekLetter instance of the 'foo' class:

```
dynamic var objectList = [alpha, beta, gamma]
```

(in fact, I'm not sure if that's the correct way to initialize a list of Objects in Realm. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Now,  I want to update my objectList so that it contains theta, omega, delta, all of which are instances of the 'bar' class.

So now,

```
dynamic var objectList = [theta, omega, delta]
```

So now, I think that the greekLetter instance has been updated and saved. But since I created alpha, beta, and gamma already, aren't they already on the database as well?

How would I go about removing those instances? Or are they negligible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm Object only be saved and updated when you put them in the `write transaction`

if you just create an `instance` of `Realm` class, you can use that `instance` like `normal instance`

for example:
you have class `'foo'` inherit from `'Object'` class

You create an instance of foo

```
let instance = foo()
```

the `'instance'` does not automatically save to database unless you save it in the `write transaction`

because that instance wasn't saved on database so you can update it like normal instance... For example:

```
foo.name = "I'm Foo"
```

To saved it to database

```
try! realm.write {
     realm.add(instance, update: true)
 }
```

now it's saved on your database... So from now then, any change you make on this instance, you have to put in the write transaction (you can not do it without the write transaction)

```
try! realm.write {
     foo.name = "I'm Foo Version 2"
 }
```

And that instance is automatically updated on the database

Comment: Thank you! makes so much more sense now!